# Alignment of text Area

Tags: html, css

Pink is my container green is my field area grey is my group in which I embed the textbox.

But all of these are aligned on left side and they are not aligned on right side. My white color text area is no showing 15px margin on right side in the gray box as in left side.

All elements should be on same alignment as on left side, but left side everything is out of the boundary.

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 420px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: hotpink;
}

fieldset {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: green;
  height: auto;
}

.form-group {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 390px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #eeefef;
  border: solid 1.5px #b3b3b3c9;
  border: solid 1px #b3b3b3c9;
  border: solid 2px #b3b3b3c9;
}

input[type="text"] {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  width: 370px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text">
      </div>


    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you using absolute positioning?

Comment: Also, you seem to be using Bootstrap classes for layout, which should handle all that for you. If you _are_ using Bootstrap, please tag the version accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have `margin` and full `width` together.

Also you have to consider the `margin` + `width` and `box-sizing`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 455px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: hotpink;
  /* box-shadow: 
            0 0 0 2px #000,
    0 0 0 3px #999,
    0 0 0 9px #fa0,
    0 0 0 10px #666,
    0 0 0 16px #fd0,
    0 0 0 18px #000,
    0 2px 6px 18px ragbag(0,0,0,0.5);
    background-color: red;
*/
}

fieldset {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: green;
  height: auto;
}

.form-group {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 405px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #eeefef;
  /* box-shadow:
                0 0 0 4px #b3b3b3,
                0 0 0 1px #b3b3b3c9,
                0 0 0 2px #e5e5e5,
                0 0 0 3.5px #f5f5f5,
                0 0 0 3px #f9f9f9;
            */
  border: solid 1.5px #b3b3b3c9;
  border: solid 1px #b3b3b3c9;
  border: solid 2px #b3b3b3c9;
}

input[type="text"] {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  width: 370px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text">
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```